# 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton' does not have a public property named 'UpdateProgress'

Tags: asp.net, .net

In a page I have a grid and 2 drop down lists inside a update panel. From drop down list user will select and selected item will saved and shown in update panel. I am also planning to use updateprogress with it.

On doing this I am getting this design time error " ***'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton' does not have a public property named 'UpdateProgress'"***

I have spent a lot of time on it but couldn't solve it. Please help me. Here is my code for this.

```
  <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Update your professional experience below"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upExperience">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="ddlCategory">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlValues">
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddNew" Text="Add New" />
                        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvExperience" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Category" HeaderText="Category" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Experience" HeaderText="Experience" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remove">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" CommandArgument="<%#Eval("ID")%>" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="upp">
                    <ProgressTemplate>
                        <img src="../Images/loading.gif" />
                    </ProgressTemplate>
                </asp:UpdateProgress>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: first correct this: `<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />` - i have replaced with single quotes

Comment: Thanks codingbiz, it solved my thing. I am not sure how I can select your comment as answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Your ImageButton server control is not well formed because of the double qoutes surroundings the Eval, so the asp:UpdateProgress is being seen as the continuation of the tag. Replace with this:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnRemove" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
```